# Namespacing Hyperlinked Serializers in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, namespaces, django-rest-framework

I'm currently doing the tutorial on [Relationships and hyperlinked API's](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/). However I've come across a strange problem that I can't seem to fix. My `serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField` and `serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField` doesnt seem to detect the namespace I'm using.

My serializers look like this

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippets:snippet-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='snippets:snippet-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

Which is pretty much the same as the tutorial except I am adding `view_name='snippets:snippet-detail'` in the serializer field.

I am creating my namespace as suggested by the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#id5), by adding `app_name = 'snippets'` above my `urlpatterns`.

This is the error I'm getting

> ImproperlyConfigured at /snippets/
>
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "snippet-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

As you see, I have approached the problem the same way other people have but without resolving the issue. Anyone have an idea about what I could try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem after reading some more about [Hyperlinks](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined) and noticing that I should add `extra_kwargs` for the `url` field `SnippetSerializer`

```
class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'snippets:snippet-detail'},
        }
```

And `UserSerializer`

```
class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'snippets:user-detail'},
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

fix this issue by modify serializer.py
we can define url, such as:

```
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippets:user-detail', lookup_field='pk')
```

or define in Meta, such as

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'url': {'view_name': 'snippet:user-detail', 'lookup_field': 'pk'},
}
```

all serializer.py code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(lookup_field="pk", view_name='snippets:snippet-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'snippets:snippet-detail', 'lookup_field': 'pk'},
        }


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(lookup_field="pk", many=True, view_name='snippets:snippet-detail', read_only=True)
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='snippets:user-detail', lookup_field='pk')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets')
        # extra_kwargs = {
        #     'url': {'view_name': 'snippet:user-detail', 'lookup_field': 'pk'},
        # }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` arguments.

```
snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='snippets:snippet-detail',
                                                   lookup_field="",
                                                   lookup_url_kwarg="", read_only=True)
```

Refer [HyperlinkedRelatedFieldDoc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)